# SQL syntax error; MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got "**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**" error only run file in some systems. But some system run file and got output.
values are coming from check box
My code is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
header("location:logout.php");
}

require 'database.php';
if($_POST['delete']) // from button name="delete"
{
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; //from name="checkbox[]"
$countCheck = count($_POST['checkbox']);
$checked = $_POST["checkbox"];
for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++)
{
echo  $del_id  = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE from user where id = $del_id";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all confirm whether the checkbox is giving a value or not. If it doesn't then your query becomes invalid: `"DELETE from user where id = "`

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh sorry, I deleted a comment, did not notice that, sorry

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i update that code to my file. Now i solved that error. But my form doesn't submit the checked values But it is working in some system except one system

Answer (score 0):

As The **'where'** clause values should be inserted in commas,so once try with following query:
**$sql = "DELETE from user where id = '".$del_id."'";.**
Hope. It may help you.

Comment: I think you mean "quotes", not commas.

Comment: i'm also use this query but i can't get answer

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++)
{
 echo  $del_id  = $checkbox[$i];
 if(isset($del_id) && $del_id !="")
   $ids[] = $del_id;
}
$ids = explode(",", $ids);

$sql = "DELETE from user where id IN ($ids)";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: why to IN?? Any specific reason??

Comment: instead firing query every time in loop you can do it as alternative. Connecting mysql server each time is time expensive. That loop may iterate 100 time or more.

Comment: Yes I know that !! But instead you should tell him his bad in sql. By the way good suggestion

Comment: thanks for your response.. Now my problem is the form doesn't submit checked values in one system but it is working fine in other systems